# Identifying Probability Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am looking to calculate the CDF of this PDF and I was wondering if anyone could help me to identify if this is a common PDF function of a well known distribution:

$$f(x) = \dfrac12e^{-|x|}$$

Comment: It is called Laplace distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution

Comment: Your comment is the answer, so please change it to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is called [Laplace distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution).